# spfx-angular-elements project working correctly on workbench but not working on sharepoint page

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, sharepoint-list, angular-elements, sharepointframework

I have created a demo with reference to the below link,

https://gonadn.medium.com/spfx-with-angular-element-crud-operations-using-pnpjs-5a8a18ed6e43

It is working correctly in the workbench. Kindly refer to the below image,
[image]

It is not working correctly on the SharePoint page.

Throwing below error in SharePoint list api call

GET [https://xyzsharepoint.sharepoint.com/sites/devsite/SitePages/_api/web/lists/getByTitle('TestList')/items?$top=2000](https://xyzsharepoint.sharepoint.com/sites/devsite/SitePages/_api/web/lists/getByTitle(%27TestList%27)/items?$top=2000) 404

Kindly refer to the below image,

[image]

Can you please assist me with the same?

Thanks :)